# Float vertically-aligned div's like columns?

Tags: html, css

I have a "container" div that will be docked to the left side of the page, and will always be 10px from the top, left, and bottom. Inside that div will be 10 small "inner" divs, which are arranged vertically. The container should always be just wide enough to hold all of the inner divs.

Here's the thing... whenever the container div cannot hold all of the inner div's in a single column (such as when the user reduces their browser height), I want the inner divs to expand over to a new "column" (but still remain inside the container div). In other words, the container div will expand horizontally as needed, so that no vertical scrollbars ever appear.

For example, if the height of the browser only goes down to div 7, then it should look like this...

```
1      8
2      9
3      10
4
5
6
7
```

Here's the jsFiddle of what I've got so far...

http://jsfiddle.net/ymESU/

And here's the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<style>
    #container {position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; } 
    .innerBoxes {display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; margin: 5px; padding: 10px; color: white;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
  <div class='innerBoxes'>1</div>
  <div class='innerBoxes'>2</div>
  <div class='innerBoxes'>3</div>
  <div class='innerBoxes'>4</div>
  <div class='innerBoxes'>5</div>
  <div class='innerBoxes'>6</div>
  <div class='innerBoxes'>7</div>
  <div class='innerBoxes'>8</div>
  <div class='innerBoxes'>9</div>
  <div class='innerBoxes'>10</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing to accomplish this?

FYI-  For this particular project, it only needs to work on modern versions of Chrome, so if the best solution requires CSS3, no problem.

Comment: I don't think there's a pure-CSS way of doing this. You'll probably need to use some flavor of JavaScript.

Comment: CSS is a styling language without the abilities of decision making. As @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas said you will need a good portion of javascript to accomplish that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only browser requirement is Chrome, then you can go ahead with CSS3 columns. Use inline-blocks instead of floats:

```
#container {position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; left: 10px; bottom: 10px; 
    border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; 
   -webkit-column-width:120px; -moz-column-width:120px;
  } 
.innerBoxes {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background: red; 
    margin: 5px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    color: white;
}
```

Here it is working in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GHMb8/2/

**update** works in Firefox too if you add `-moz-column-width:120px;` (new fiddle)

Comment: Thanks Faust, but the inner div's will need to be arranged vertically (they are arranged horizontally in your example). Is this possible to do?

Comment: elements need to be aligned vertically first, then horizontally

Comment: Are you looking in Chrome? They are arranged vertically, first, in Chrome.

Comment: ...also,just updated to work in Firefox (use `-moz-column-width`) ... definitely aligning *vertically first* in Firefox as well as Chrome

Comment: Why have you added `height:1000px`? That breaks it in my opinion.

Comment: I only added `height:1000px` to get a greater height than provided by the tiny jsfiddle window -- allowing for the 7 boxes the OP shows in the quuestion. It doesn't break anything. Remove the height, and it still works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/GHMb8/3/

Comment: Just tested the updated Fiddle in Chrome. That would work great if I wanted to specify a fixed height for the container. But the height of the container needs to be "liquid" (which is why I mentioned that it will always be 10 px from the top, left, and bottom). Is this possible?

Comment: Ah ok... don't have that problem with my 1440px screen height. :)

Comment: @NotQuiteThereYet: fixed height is *not required*. See my last comment.

Comment: Ahh OK... just removed the "height" property. Seems to work just fine now. Thank you! :)

Comment: I just realized that I need to have a fixed width for the container for this to work. That makes it look bad whenever it shows either 1 or 3 columns.  Dang, so close!

Comment: No, the fixed width for the container is not necessary either. Take it off and see: http://jsfiddle.net/GHMb8/4/. I also just updated the answer removing both the fixed height and width from the container.

Comment: That just makes the container take up the entire width of the screen when you do that. I was hoping to have the container just wide enough to hold its contents, because I will need to put other stuff on the page too.

Comment: I see -- that's what you meant by "The container should always be just wide enough to hold all of the inner divs." I missed that. Well, I think we've reached the limit of a pure-CSS solution.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate all your help nonetheless! :)