# tiles from up to down not from left to right in container

Tags: jquery, css, height

I would like to make tiles/thumbnails showing from up to down like this:[image]

When i just put tiles inside container it wont work like float:left to fit container then next line.
In this case tiles ( red ) just goes outside container ( black ).

[EXAMPLE ON CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/Szymon_Dziewonski/pen/dpLEl)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Float vertically-aligned div's like columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155811/float-vertically-aligned-divs-like-columns)

Comment: Thats the best anwser so far ! :) thank you :)!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a width on the container, that way it will restrict the boxes. By doing this, it allows you to set `float: left;` on the smaller boxes.

*Edit: updated link*: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/boxtq

Comment: but as u can see it is different counting = count from left to right 1, 2, 3, 4, not from up to down like on picture

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński I would suggest creating a class called `.col`, and the putting them in there. I will update my answer with the solution.

Comment: +1, but I think it should still work without the relative positioning. Also this: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @JonnySooter It would. I just forgot to take it out because I tried a few other things before I realised what the problem was.

Comment: yes that is solution for this problem but my point is , do u know if there is any way to make it without .col ?

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński It depends on what browsers you're supporting. I would suggest looking at the link in the comment on your question if you are supporting only webkit browsers and Firefox. You could use a jQuery plug-in or regular JS, but it would be overkill.

Comment: I was thinking about jQuery in that case but i cant think any solution. Just looking for anwser without those class="col". If u have any idea how to do it on jQuery or i was thinking about nth-child too but without constructive result. I would be glad if some1 would help.

Answer (score 0):

If the tiles stay the same height, then you can employ this strategy. It doesn't require an extra .col tag, but it requires you to define which tag goes on top. I am at work right now, so i can not access JSfiddle. This works on IE7 so I am certain it will work (better?) in FF and other standard compliant browsers.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
 <div class="top">6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
 <div class="top">11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
 <div class="top">16</div>
  <div>17</div>
  <div>18</div>
  <div>19</div>
  <div>20</div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 520px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.wrapper div {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    border: 5px solid #808080;
}
.wrapper div.top {
    clear: none;
    margin-top: -310px;
}
.wrapper div.top + div {
    clear: none;
    margin-top: -230px;
}
.wrapper div.top + div + div {
    clear: none;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
.wrapper div.top + div + div + div {
    clear: none;
    margin-top: -70px;
}
.wrapper div.top + div + div + div + div {
    clear: none;
}
```

[image: IE7 Rendering]

Comment: Thats perfect man, it will get use for me, I will write to ad every 5th elemnt class=top to div and will be great, and just few aditional line in css. Thank You !